# Want to sort my list of files according to date using Unix

Tags: unix, sorting, date-time, file-search

My list of files is like ...

```
Oct 13 03:50 TEST_j002_26047.trc
Oct 11 17:10 TEST_j001_26047.trc
Oct 10 10:43 TEST_j000_6096.trc
Oct 12 02:52 TEST_j001_26048.trc
```

I want my output in a sorted way according to date:

```
Oct 10 10:43 TEST_j000_6096.trc
Oct 11 17:10 TEST_j001_26047.trc
Oct 12 02:52 TEST_j001_26048.trc
Oct 13 03:50 TEST_j002_26047.trc
```

Comment: ls -rt not enough?

Comment: This is the natural sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ls -lt` or `ls -ltr`.

From the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) of `ls`

```
   -l     use a long listing format
   -t     sort by modification time, newest first
   -r, --reverse
          reverse order while sorting
```

Answer (score 0):

In what context? 
If you just want to list them chronologically, use `ls -tr`. 
The `-t` option
specifies that files should be sorted by modification date/time. 
In a dubious design decision, the default is newest first. 
`-r` **r**everses that, putting the most recent files last.

If you want a glob (e.g., `*` or `*.trc`) to do this, is becomes trickier.